# ASP.Net user control with "n" multiple properties

Tags: asp.net, properties, user-controls

I want my user control to have the functionality of taking n different parameters. n is not meant to be fix. 
For example one time I will pass 3 strings to it and next time 12:

```
<mycompany:MyUC runat="server" ID="mctID" Para1="test1" Para2="test3" Para3="test4" Para4="test8"  />

<mycompany:MyUC runat="server" ID="mctID" Para1="test1" Para2="test3" Para3="test4" Para4="test8" Para5="test1" Para6="test3" Para7="test4" Para8="test8" />
```

Is this possible without defining the properties in advance?

Comment: Given MyUC is ultimately a class, how would you write a class that had an undefined number of properties? You need a method or property that takes an IEnumerable of values instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another method to achieve my goal. The solution was to use the PersistenceMode attribute in my property together with my own class "SelectControl":

```
 <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _
        Public Property SelectControls() As List(Of SelectControl)
            Get
....
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As List(Of SelectControl))
...
            End Set
        End Property


                        <myCompany:QDirectEditAdapter runat="server" ID="deaContactsSupplier" EditControlID="grdContactsSupplier" EditControlKeyField="SSC_USR_ID_FK">
                            <SelectControls>
                                <myCompany:SelectControl ControlID="cboUserSelection" ContainerID="pnlUserSelection" KeyField="USR_ID" ActivityColumns="USR_USERNAME, USR_NAME" />
                                <myCompany:SelectControl ControlID="qacProductSelection" ContainerID="pnlProductSelection" KeyField="NR" ActivityColumns="SSC_APPLICATION" />
                            </SelectControls>
                        </myCompany:QDirectEditAdapter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible unless you pass it with a delimiter of some kind:

```
  MyProperty="Value1, Value2, Value3"
```

And then split it with "," in the code side.

But I think it would be better just to have a function in the control and pass the values for example as a string array (VB.Net syntax):

In control:

```
Public Sub SetMyValues(values As String())
    ' Store in viewstate or do what you need
End Sub
```

When initializin the control, call from the page or wherever you need:

```
MyControl1.SetMyValues({"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"})
```